# Как правильно написать окончание?

Tags: окончание

Как в подобных предложениях правильно написать?

"Начинай с любого часа и минуты, но только не с **той (тех)**, когда это произойдёт".

Склоняюсь к "тех".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предпочтительный вариант: "Начинай с любого часа и минуты, но только не с тех, когда это произойдёт".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Решающим фактором для выбора мн.числа является постпозиция определения, например: Сначала выберите упражнение и задание, нетрудные для выполнения.

Исключением могут являться документы, в которых важна смысловая точность, например: (1)Вы должны построить каменный дом и гараж. (2)Вы должны построить каменные дом и гараж. Во втором случае ясно, что оба строения будут из камня.

Материал из "Практической стилистики современного русского языка", РАН, 2012 г.

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксис беспомощен перед такой семантикой... Проще говоря, смысл фразы чрезвычайно туманный.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: с той. Минута и час в ед.ч. Местоимение "той" относится не к двум словам сразу, а только к одному в отдельности.

Comment: Правила не нашла. Но почему надо согласовывать с минутой, а не со словом "любой"? С любого, но не с того... По смыслу, конечно, что-то происходит скорее в минуту, чем в час. А если было бы: Начинай с любого раздела и страницы, но только не с...

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, объясните, зачем сочинять такие "неудобоваримые" словесные конструкции, если они вызывают подобные грамматические затруднения? Пишите тексты простые и понятные, во всяком случае - посильные Вам(автору) для написания.